# Redirect to page after sweetalert2 disappear

Tags: javascript, redirect, sweetalert2

When I save data to mysql, it saves and a success sweetalert2 shows the response. After timer out it disappears but doesn't execute function.

My code is as below:

```js
swal({
  position: 'center',
  type: 'warning',
  title: 'Exam already exist',
  showConfirmButton: false,
  timer: 2500,
},
function () {
  window.location.href = 'examination.php';
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@7.33.1/dist/sweetalert2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@7.33.1/dist/sweetalert2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `onClose()` function

```js
swal({
  position: 'center',
  type: 'warning',
  title: 'Exam already exist',
  showConfirmButton: false,
  timer: 2500,
  onClose: () => {
    window.location.href="https://google.com"
  }
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@7.33.1/dist/sweetalert2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@7.33.1/dist/sweetalert2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Saurabh Mistry, after putting all the given codes again, it worked.